# Stripe.NET add bank account using token to Stripe Managed Account

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I've searched through Jayme Davis' documentation, and I cannot find how to add a bank account using a token to a Stripe Managed Account.  The only way it appears to add a bank account in the documentation, is by using the CustomerBankAccount object, which requires a CustomerID as a parameter, and does not work with an AccountID (i.e. Managed Account ID).  I essentially would like to make this request (from Stipe's website) using Stripe.NET and C# code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts/acct_1032D82eZvKYlo2C/external_accounts \
   -u sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: \
   -d external_account=btok_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ExternalBankAccount` property for this and see an example in the test [here](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/cdd6a92633e3cfc38550e6b93975ff7ab5e1ef13/src/Stripe.net.Tests/account/when_updating_an_account_with_a_bank_account_token.cs#L34)

```
var params = new StripeAccountUpdateOptions();
params.ExternalBankAccount = new StripeAccountBankAccountOptions
{
    TokenId = _token.Id
}

var accountService = new StripeAccountService();
StripeAccount response = accountService.Update("acct_XXX", params);
```